# From Excel VBA- Check if Access Table Exists / If Not, Create/Copy

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am working with an Access databasein VBA through Excel. I want to check if a table in the DB exists, and then if not, I want to create the table using the same fields/definitions as a table labeled "Blank" in that database. I can simply copy/rename Blank if necessary.

I found a way to check if the table exists using the following (not sure if it is the best way though).

```
Set objCatalog = CreateObject("ADOX.catalog")
objCatalog.ActiveConnection = dbConn
For i = 0 To objCatalog.Tables.Count - 1
    If objCatalog.Tables.Item(i).Name = tbName Then tbExists = True
Next
```

This works, but I'm struggling to find a way to copy or create a new table using Blank's fields/definitions when the destination table does not exist (tbExists = False).

Comment: Thank you all for the help.  Apparently my entire approach to the DB design was flawed, so this question is moot, but I very much appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

This might be another way to check if a table exists by checking if the Table Definition returns anything.

A TableDef object represents the stored definition of a base table or a linked table (Microsoft Access workspaces only).

```
Set exampleDB = workSpace.OpenDatabase(DatabaseName)

Set tableDefinition = exampleDB.TableDefs(TableName)
tableExists = Err.Number = 0
```

For more information

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/tabledef-object-dao

Comment: Nice to know but doesn't really address the question "struggling to find a way to copy or create the new table".

Answer (score 1):

**Creating access object from excel vba**

```
Sub TableExistOrCreate()

    Dim appAccess As Object, tbl As Object
    Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

    appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase ("C:\Users\santosh\Desktop\test.accdb")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set tbl = appAccess.currentdata.AllTables("Test")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If tbl Is Nothing Then
        appAccess.docmd.CopyObject , "Test", 0, "Blank"
    End If

    Set appAccess = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\June\Umpires.accdb"
cn.Execute "SELECT Blank.* INTO [" & tbName & "] FROM Blank"
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
```

The new table won't actually show in the Navigation Pane without doing something else, like Compact & Repair or Close/Reopen database or run code that selects the table in Navigation Pane or somehow refreshing the Pane (hide/unhide Pane does that).

Some field property settings won't be carried over (AllowZeroLength = No). Calculated type field will cause run-time error as will multi-value field.

DoCmd.CopyObject and DoCmd.TransferDatabase can exactly copy table. DoCmd.Rename can simply rename table. All will require code that declares and opens Access database object variable.